# How to set up object layout from UIView using protocols

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift-protocols

I try to set up objects layout which have a reference to UIView using protocols. My view class looks like that:

```
protocol FirstViewLayout {
   var label: String { get }
   var text: String { get }
}

class FirstView: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel! // reference to object in storyboard
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton! // reference to object in storyboard

init(layout: FirstViewLayout){
       super.init(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
       label.text = layout.text
       button.setTitle(layout.text, forState: .Normal)
   }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
   }
}//end class
```

then I create a separate swift file where I create simple struct and set the values for objects from view

```
struct FirstViewStruct: FirstViewLayout {

   var label: String { return "Test" }
   var text: String { return "TEST" }

}
```

and after that I go to `ViewControler` and set it up in `viewDidLoad()` like that:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let layout = FirstView(layout: FirstViewStruct())
    self.view.addSubview(layout)

}
```

in this case I recive an error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional` in this moment:

```
label.text = layout.text
```

and I don't know why. Can somebody help me solve this issue?

Comment: You probably need to to layout!.text

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot have default value in struct.

Create an init that fills value :

```
convenience init() {
    self.label  = "test"
    self.text = "test"
    super.init()
}
```